# Dropwizard sends back 404 Not Found for part of registered endpoints

Tags: dropwizard

I have a simple resource which exposes CRUD endpoints.

```
@Path("/stores/{store-id}/register")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RegisterResource {

@GET
@Path("/{register-id}")
public Response getRegisterById(@PathParam("store-id") Long storeId, @PathParam("register-id") Long registerId) { impl }

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response save(RegisterDTO registerDto, @PathParam("store-id") Long storeId, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) { impl }

@PUT
@Path("/{register-id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response update(RegisterDTO registerDto, @PathParam("store-id") Long storeId, @PathParam("register-id") Long registerId) { impl }

@DELETE
@Path("/{register-id}")
public Response delete(@PathParam("store-id") Long storeId, @PathParam("register-id") Long registerId) { impl }

}
```

Dropwizard successfully register my resource:

```
INFO  [2017-03-07 07:03:49,765] io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig: The following paths were found for the configured resources:

POST    /stores/{store-id}/register (api.resources.RegisterResource)
DELETE  /stores/{store-id}/register/{register-id} (api.resources.RegisterResource)
GET     /stores/{store-id}/register/{register-id} (api.resources.RegisterResource)
PUT     /stores/{store-id}/register/{register-id} (api.resources.RegisterResource)
```

Only POST requests are processed. When I send GET/PUT/DELETE request - I receive back 404 Not Found. No exceptions are thrown/logged.
There are also two interesting facts:
1) I have a filter which checks Authorization header. It does not log any requests except POST.
2) I log incoming request int the first statement of every method of my resource. But only requests for POST are logged.

The most interesting fact is that I a day ago and everything was OK. Can't figure out where the problem is... I will appreciate any suggestions what went wrong.

Comment: Can not reproduce. Can you update with the curls that you are trying and tell us what you changed in the last X days?

Comment: *most interesting fact is that I a day ago and everything was OK* what changed?

Comment: Which tool you are using to test APIs ?

Comment: The problem was in another one resource's @Path annotation and URI matching.

Comment: what was the exact issue?

Comment: @KostyantynPanchenko Please answer your own question with as much detail as you can. Thanks!